# How to use the user control in list with binding?

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, event-handling, wpf-controls

I have a user control called (**ProfileControl**) which has a **image** with two **textblock** and a **button**. What I want is to show the data from the SQL Server in the main page of my application view each control next to each other horizontally. And respond when I press the button in the control.

I will be using a **scrollviewer** for the automatic resizing. But I am not sure on what to use if it is a **listbox**, **listview** etc. also, I am not sure on how to do the building correctly. Please also how can I enable the custom event handler of the button in the XAML.

What I did so far:-

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <ListBox Name="profileList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <profileControl:ProfileControl />
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Thanks,

Update: as with the responses below I did the following

```
<ListBox Name="profileList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <!--<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <profileControl:ProfileControl />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>-->
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
```

I commented the ItemTemplete section and I did manage to see the data from the database. The only thing missing is I need to enable the event handle of the user control (which is a button) which is I need to write in the xmal (OnClickUserControl="UC_OutButton" // which is the event handler and the target method).

But I dont know how to do.. Please advise me.

Comment: First of all, your ScrollViewer is useless (already contained in the ListBox) and your StackPanel too (which contains only one item).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change how items are stacked then you need to change `ItemsPanel` of your `Listbox`

```
<ListBox Name="profileList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <profileControl:ProfileControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

also your `ScrollViewer` is not needed as it's already part of default template for `ListBox`. As for the `Button` not sure what you mean by *enable the custom event handler of the button in the XAML* but `Button.Command` should be bound to some `ICommand` in your view model which will be displayed by your `ProfileControl` control

Comment: It is working and looks as I want it. But it is not showing the data binding in the profileControl. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you change `DataContext` somewhere inside `ProfileControl`? `DataContext` of `ProfileControl` should be set to instance of whatever is the item in your `ItemsSource`

Comment: I kept it as it is. Since I am not sure how to do the binding. I tried adding DataContext="{binding}" to profileControl but it gave an error.

Comment: Without seeing your control and view model behind it it's hard to say what's wrong but it seems that binding context is the problem. If, as you say, you don't change `DataContext` inside your control code and all bindings are valid for view model behind item of `ItemSource` then XAML above should work as item will be passed through `DataContext` into your control.